# How many nodejs event loops works on pm2 cluster with few instances?

Tags: node.js, pm2

So, if I run `"pm2 start app.js -i 3"` how many nodejs event loops do I get?
I think about it because I heart that event loop eats a lot of resources from nodejs app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 event loops for three separate nodejs instance.

If you think about browser, ***in general*** every tab has their own event-loop. But, it varies on the implementation of the browser. For example: chrome uses Process-per-site-instance which means, same site opened in multiple tab will be rendered by the same process.

Comment: Are there any alternatives for pm2 zero-downtime with one event loop for all instances? Can I do it over nodejs threads maybe?

Comment: One event loop for all instance is not how NodeJS is designed.